# Why this sin cos look up table inaccurate when radian is large?

Tags: c, arrays, math, trigonometry

I want to create a sin cos look up table for optimization, by using an array index from 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`, so that 0 radian is index 0, `pi/2` radian is `UCHAR_MAX/4`:

sincos.h

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
int sini[UCHAR_MAX];
int cosi[UCHAR_MAX];
#define MAGNIFICATION 256
#define SIN(i) sini[i]/MAGNIFICATION
#define COS(i) cosi[i]/MAGNIFICATION

void initTable(){
    for(int i=0;i<UCHAR_MAX;i++){
        sini[i]=sinf(i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX)*MAGNIFICATION;
        cosi[i]=cosf(i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX)*MAGNIFICATION;
    }
}
```

the reason of using `UCHAR_MAX` as max is I want to make the good use of unsigned char overflow to simulates the radian thats varies from 0 to `2*pi` only : for example, if the value of radian is `2*pi`, the index of array becomes `UCHAR_MAX`, because it overflows, it automatically becomes 0 and no mod is required (if I use 0 to 360 as domain I may need to calculate `index%360` every time). Then I test it with some radian values:

```
float rad[]={2.0f,4.0f,6.0f,8.0f,10.0f,-2.0f,-4.0f,-6.0f,-8.0f,-10.0f};
```

like the following:

```
#include "sincos.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    initTable();
    unsigned char radToIndex;
    float rad[]={2.0f,4.0f,6.0f,8.0f,10.0f,-2.0f,-4.0f,-6.0f,-8.0f,-10.0f};
    int scalar=123;
    printf("scalar=%d\n",scalar);
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(rad)/sizeof(float);i++){
        radToIndex=rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI;
        printf("%d*sin(%f) : %f , %d\n",scalar,rad[i],scalar*sinf(rad[i]),scalar*SIN(radToIndex));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I test the table with `123*sin(radian)`,found the results starts go beyond the actual one when the magnitude of radian increases (when radian is 10 or -10):

```
scalar=123
123*sin(2.000000) : 111.843582 , 111
123*sin(4.000000) : -93.086708 , -92
123*sin(6.000000) : -34.368107 , -35
123*sin(8.000000) : 121.691063 , 122
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -61
123*sin(-2.000000) : -111.843582 , -112
123*sin(-4.000000) : 93.086708 , 90
123*sin(-6.000000) : 34.368107 , 38
123*sin(-8.000000) : -121.691063 , -122
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 59
```

and test with another data:

```
float rad[]={0.01f,0.1f,1.0f,10.0f,100.0f,1000.0f,-0.01f,-0.1f,-1.0f,-10.0f,-100.0f,-1000.0f};
```

output:

```
scalar=123
123*sin(0.010000) : 1.229980 , 0
123*sin(0.100000) : 12.279510 , 12
123*sin(1.000000) : 103.500931 , 102
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -61
123*sin(100.000000) : -62.282974 , -97
123*sin(1000.000000) : 101.706184 , -25
123*sin(-0.010000) : -1.229980 , 0
123*sin(-0.100000) : -12.279510 , -8
123*sin(-1.000000) : -103.500931 , -100
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 59
123*sin(-100.000000) : 62.282974 , 98
123*sin(-1000.000000) : -101.706184 , 22
```

The error increase when magnitude increases, so I am quite sure the table becomes inaccurate when radian is large. In sincos.h there is a value MAGNIFICATION to control the accuracy, I changed it from 256 to 4096, but it seems no much improvement:

```
scalar=123
123*sin(0.010000) : 1.229980 , 0
123*sin(0.100000) : 12.279510 , 12
123*sin(1.000000) : 103.500931 , 102
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -62
123*sin(100.000000) : -62.282974 , -97
123*sin(1000.000000) : 101.706184 , -25
123*sin(-0.010000) : -1.229980 , 0
123*sin(-0.100000) : -12.279510 , -9
123*sin(-1.000000) : -103.500931 , -100
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 59
123*sin(-100.000000) : 62.282974 , 99
123*sin(-1000.000000) : -101.706184 , 22
```

why would that happen? is there logical error of the table?

Comment: How to you messure the accuracy?

Answer (score 5):

[Edit]

Code experiences problems as the angle increases past 360 degrees due to wrong "modulo" arithmetic in OP's following code.  The product `rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI` is converted to an (8-bit) `unsigned char` which is a modulo 256, yet code is scaling tables and code by `UCHAR_MAX` (255).  The last point of this answer details aspects of this, yet it is clear that tables and code should be use 256, not 255.

```
unsigned char radToIndex;
radToIndex=rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI; // wrong scaling
radToIndex=rad[i]*(UCHAR_MAX+1)/2/M_PI;  // right
```

Further, note OP's code has undefined behavior when `radToIndex == UCHAR_MAX` as that is an invalid index to `int sini[UCHAR_MAX];`.

Using above fix and 3 below fixes: table size 256, round index, round the value of sine, use double for table creation results in:

```
123*sin(2.000000) : 111.843584 , 112
123*sin(4.000000) : -93.086707 , -93
123*sin(6.000000) : -34.368106 , -35
123*sin(8.000000) : 121.691064 , 121
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -65
123*sin(-2.000000) : -111.843584 , -112
123*sin(-4.000000) : 93.086707 , 93
123*sin(-6.000000) : 34.368106 , 35
123*sin(-8.000000) : -121.691064 , -121
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 65
```

---

Code is also experiencing [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) or more preciously: double truncation.

`radToIndex=rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI;` truncates toward 0. So the index is made smaller, not closest.

Table creation `sini[i]=sinf(i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX)*MAGNIFICATION;` also truncates toward 0. So the `sini[]` is made smaller, not closest `int`.

To improve, simply round to nearest with `round()`.

```
sini[i] = (int) roundf(sinf(i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX)*MAGNIFICATION);
radToIndex= (int) round(rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI);
```

---

As a general note, since `float` is typically 24 bit precision and `int` likely 31+sign, use `double` for table creation for additional improvements.

```
sini[i] = (int) round(sin(i*2.0*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX)*MAGNIFICATION);
```

---

Further, recommend using `UCHAR_MAX + 1` See [BAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling#Binary_angles):

Off by 1.

> the index of array becomes UCHAR_MAX, because it overflows, it automatically becomes 0

`UCHAR_MAX` is not overflow, `UCHAR_MAX + 1` overflows and becomes 0.  (`unsigned char` math)

```
int sini[UCHAR_MAX+1];
for (int i=0; i<(UCHAR_MAX+1); i++) {
  // Rather than `i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX`, use 
  sini[i]=sinf(i*2*M_PI/(UCHAR_MAX + 1))*MAGNIFICATION;
```

Comment: Using `double`and `sin()` in table creation useful when `MAGNIFICATION > 1e23`.

Answer (score 0):

**Source of problem**

It looks like you are getting errors from rounding of floating point numbers and assigning floating point numbers to an `unsigned char`.

The following program, adapted from your posted code, demonstrates how the index starts to deviate even after you round the floating point number.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int sini[UCHAR_MAX];
int cosi[UCHAR_MAX];
double angle[UCHAR_MAX];


#define MAGNIFICATION 256
#define SIN(i) sini[i]/MAGNIFICATION
#define COS(i) cosi[i]/MAGNIFICATION

void initTable()
{
   double M_PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);
   for(int i=0;i<UCHAR_MAX;i++)
   {
      angle[i] = i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX;
      sini[i]=sinf(angle[i])*MAGNIFICATION;
      cosi[i]=cosf(angle[i])*MAGNIFICATION;
   }
}

#include <stdio.h>

void test3()
{
   int radToIndexInt;
   unsigned char radToIndexChar;
   float radTemp;
   float rad[]={2.0f,4.0f,6.0f,8.0f,10.0f,-2.0f,-4.0f,-6.0f,-8.0f,-10.0f};
   double M_PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);

   for(int i=0;i<sizeof(rad)/sizeof(float);i++)
   {
      radTemp = rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI;
      radToIndexInt = round(radTemp);
      radToIndexInt %= UCHAR_MAX;
      if ( radToIndexInt < 0 )
      {
         radToIndexInt += UCHAR_MAX;
      }

      radToIndexChar = round(radTemp);

      printf("radToIndexInt: %d, radToIndexChar: %d\n",
             radToIndexInt, radToIndexChar);

   }
}

int main()
{
   initTable();

   test3();

   return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program:

```
radToIndexInt: 81, radToIndexChar: 81
radToIndexInt: 162, radToIndexChar: 162
radToIndexInt: 244, radToIndexChar: 244
radToIndexInt: 70, radToIndexChar: 69
radToIndexInt: 151, radToIndexChar: 150
radToIndexInt: 174, radToIndexChar: 175
radToIndexInt: 93, radToIndexChar: 94
radToIndexInt: 11, radToIndexChar: 12
radToIndexInt: 185, radToIndexChar: 187
radToIndexInt: 104, radToIndexChar: 106
```

**Solution**

By using

```
  radToIndex=round(radTemp);
  radToIndex %= UCHAR_MAX;
  if ( radToIndex < 0 )
  {
     radToIndex += UCHAR_MAX;
  }
```

to compute the index, I get very close answers:

Here's a program, once again adapted from your posted code, demonstrates that using the above logic works.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int sini[UCHAR_MAX];
int cosi[UCHAR_MAX];
double angle[UCHAR_MAX];


#define MAGNIFICATION 256
#define SIN(i) sini[i]/MAGNIFICATION
#define COS(i) cosi[i]/MAGNIFICATION

void initTable()
{
   double M_PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);
   for(int i=0;i<UCHAR_MAX;i++)
   {
      angle[i] = i*2*M_PI/UCHAR_MAX;
      sini[i]=sinf(angle[i])*MAGNIFICATION;
      cosi[i]=cosf(angle[i])*MAGNIFICATION;
   }
}

#include <stdio.h>

void test2()
{
   int radToIndex;
   float radTemp;
   int scalar=123;
   float rad[]={0.01f,0.1f,1.0f,10.0f,100.0f,1000.0f,-0.01f,-0.1f,-1.0f,-10.0f,-100.0f,-1000.0f};
   double M_PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);

   printf("scalar=%d\n",scalar);
   for(int i=0;i<sizeof(rad)/sizeof(float);i++)
   {
      radTemp = rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI;
      radToIndex=round(radTemp);
      radToIndex %= UCHAR_MAX;
      if ( radToIndex < 0 )
      {
         radToIndex += UCHAR_MAX;
      }
      printf("%d*sin(%f) : %f , %d\n",
             scalar,rad[i],scalar*sinf(rad[i]),scalar*SIN(radToIndex));

   }
}

void test1()
{
   int radToIndex;
   float radTemp;
   int scalar=123;
   float rad[]={2.0f,4.0f,6.0f,8.0f,10.0f,-2.0f,-4.0f,-6.0f,-8.0f,-10.0f};
   double M_PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);

   printf("scalar=%d\n",scalar);
   for(int i=0;i<sizeof(rad)/sizeof(float);i++)
   {
      radTemp = rad[i]*UCHAR_MAX/2/M_PI;
      radToIndex=round(radTemp);
      radToIndex %= UCHAR_MAX;
      if ( radToIndex < 0 )
      {
         radToIndex += UCHAR_MAX;
      }
      printf("%d*sin(%f) : %f , %d\n",
             scalar,rad[i],scalar*sinf(rad[i]),scalar*SIN(radToIndex));

   }
}

int main()
{
   initTable();

   test1();
   test2();

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
scalar=123
123*sin(2.000000) : 111.843582 , 111
123*sin(4.000000) : -93.086708 , -92
123*sin(6.000000) : -34.368107 , -32
123*sin(8.000000) : 121.691063 , 121
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -67
123*sin(-2.000000) : -111.843582 , -111
123*sin(-4.000000) : 93.086708 , 92
123*sin(-6.000000) : 34.368107 , 32
123*sin(-8.000000) : -121.691063 , -121
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 67
scalar=123
123*sin(0.010000) : 1.229980 , 0
123*sin(0.100000) : 12.279510 , 12
123*sin(1.000000) : 103.500931 , 103
123*sin(10.000000) : -66.914597 , -67
123*sin(100.000000) : -62.282974 , -63
123*sin(1000.000000) : 101.706184 , 102
123*sin(-0.010000) : -1.229980 , 0
123*sin(-0.100000) : -12.279510 , -12
123*sin(-1.000000) : -103.500931 , -103
123*sin(-10.000000) : 66.914597 , 67
123*sin(-100.000000) : 62.282974 , 63
123*sin(-1000.000000) : -101.706184 , -102
```